# Field available for Reporting in Salesforce

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

Are there any specific field data types which are not available for reporting in salesforce ?
Or all fields can be used in reports?
Apart from checking manually under setup-> Report Types ->  available fields for any specific object , is there any way we can check if some specific fields are available for reporting or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fields on all objects that support reporting can be included in a report. Some fields may have restrictions on which filters may be used (e.g. no filtering allowed, or only equals/not-equals). Note that reports respect field level and record level security, so a field or record may not appear depending on a user's profile settings and/or permission sets. Some "standard reports" also don't include custom fields, but that is a report-specific limitation.

Comment: Regarding - 'Some fields may have restrictions on which filters may be used (e.g. no filtering allowed, or only equals/not-equals). ', How to find out this?

Comment: @AnkitaGupta They're all related to specific data types. Once you know how a data type behaves, all fields of that type will behave the same. For example, encrypted fields don't support starts with, contains, etc. Multiselect is the only type that allows includes/excludes, etc. I don't know of a single resource that contains this information. Basically, there are normal fields, long fields (long text, long rich text), encrypted fields, picklists, and multiselect lists.